# Porting from Eigen 2 to Eigen 3

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, eigen, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the [turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration) package converted to work with Eigen 3 (new in Fuerte). I've resolved the dependency issues but still get errors with rosmake:

> src/calibrate_kinect_checkerboard.cpp:67:41:
> error: conversion from
> ‘tf::Quaternion’ to non-scalar type
> ‘btQuaternion’ requested
>
> src/calibrate_kinect_checkerboard.cpp:68:38:
> error: conversion from ‘tf::Vector3’
> to non-scalar type ‘btVector3’
> requested
>
> src/calibrate_kinect_checkerboard.cpp:
> In member function ‘bool
> CalibrateKinectCheckerboard::calibrate(std::string)’:
> src/calibrate_kinect_checkerboard.cpp:317:5:
> error:
> ‘estimateRigidTransformationSVD’ is
> not a member of ‘pcl’not a member of ‘pcl’

I'd like to get the [Eigen2 support modes](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/Eigen2SupportModes.html) enabled using the pre-processor *#define EIGEN2_SUPPORT_STAGE10_FULL_EIGEN2_API* but putting that at the top of my .cpp files is not working. Does that go somewhere in the *CMake* or *manifest.xml* files? Has anyone already gotten the Eigen->TF working with Eigen 3?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33553/porting-from-eigen-2-to-eigen-3/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-10**:
Non of these errors appear to be Eigen related.  I also suggest that you file a ticket for this so the maintainer will be notified. https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/newticket?component=turtlebot_arm&type=defect&&turtlebot_arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to resolve the first two error messages with the following replacement:

On line 68 convert:

```
btQuaternion quat = trans.getRotation();
btVector3 origin = trans.getOrigin();
```

To:

```
btQuaternion quat( trans.getRotation()[0], trans.getRotation()[1],                                                 
                   trans.getRotation()[2], trans.getRotation()[3] );                                                                                                                                                                                                       
btVector3 origin( trans.getOrigin()[0], trans.getOrigin()[1], trans.getOrigin()[2]);
```

But I still haven't resolved other issues, such that I have not been able to successfully compile the package yet.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0